# Setting Layout in ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecuted is problematic

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razorgenerator

I'm trying to set the layout path in a custom `ActionFilterAttribute` I have written as follow:

```
public class LayoutInjecterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(filterContext);
        var result = filterContext.Result as ViewResult;
        if (result != null)
        {
            result.MasterName = "~/Views/Layouts/Test.cshtml"
        }
    }
}
```

In here Test.cshtml is precompiled view (with the help of `RazorGenerator`) in a different project.

But it gives me the error:

> The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Home/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
>   ~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
>   ~/Views/Layouts/Test.cshtml

and controller actually is simple:

```
[LayoutInjecter]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you create the controller Layouts?

Comment: No, there isn't any controller named 'Layouts'

Comment: Please add a new controller called layouts and then create a new action result called Test and return the view, and that should be work

Comment: is the Layouts folder available in all projects ?

Comment: No. Only library project has that folder. I've tried to add an empty folder to the mvc project but nothing changed :(

Answer (score 7):

The error shows that `LayoutInjecter` is working fine. You said:

> In here Test.cshtml is precompiled view in a different project.

**But**, Using razor views from a different (from outside the web project) is not supported out of the box. However there's a tool to precompile razor views and then you can put them in any DLL which called [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/). 
*The compiler can't find the specified master layout file and shows this error.*

For more information look at

- [Precompiled Razor View Using RazorGenerator MVC and
  PreCompiledViewEngine in MVC 4](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/97fc7a/article-precompiled-razor-view-using-razorgenerator-mvc-and/).
- [Compile your asp.net mvc Razor views into a seperate dll](http://www.chrisvandesteeg.nl/2010/11/22/embedding-pre-compiled-razor-views-in-your-dll/)

**Edit: How did the PrecompiledMvcViewEngine know which view to render?**

`PrecompiledMvcViewEngine` *still relies on the ASP.NET MVC Views folder convention*, using *relative file paths* to locate the views. However, this is slightly misleading. The `PrecompiledMvcViewEngine` *doesn’t look at physical files*; it looks for the `System.Web.WebPages.PageVirtualPathAttribute` that the Razor Single File Generator adds to every view that it generates that includes the view’s relative file path.

**Edit 2:** I believe the guidance for your problem would be found in [GitHub](https://github.com/RazorGenerator/RazorGenerator/issues/29).

Comment: I've actually did with RazorGenerator.

Comment: @Kaan I put an edit to my answer. Could you check if the generated files appear in the `obj` directory of your project and that the views get compiled in to your project assembly?

Comment: I don't know why but, if the both projects are in same solution it works. But if they are in seperate solution, it doesn't work!

Comment: @Kaan See my **Edit 2** please.

Comment: All my views are marked as "Content". I don't think it helps me.

Answer (score 4):

It works. Make sure the layout path `"~/Views/Layouts/Test.cshtml"` is correct.

Also, make sure that "Test.cshtml" is a layout page, and not a view / partial view.

Comment: Path is correct and Test.chstml is just a layout page.

Answer (score 3):

Change `result.MasterName = "~/Views/Layouts/Test.cshtml"` to `result.MasterName ="~/Views/Shared/Test.cshtml"`. 
The Framework by convention looks in the ~/Views/Shared/ directory in your asp.net mvc solution for your layout pages. 
It appears to me you are dynamically or at runtime selecting a master page.